# How to write a synchronized function in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, synchronized

Can someone please help me to write a synchronized function in Node.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/36978

[Source Code - https://github.com/raj-here/leaning-node-2](https://github.com/raj-here/leaning-node-2)

What I want, when multiple request trying to access same function it should be locked for one until the data has not been processed within that function.

It is working fine when I'm sending one request at a time, But when users sends multiple request at a time, logics gonna break (It should be self-explanatory! when you will look at below code).

I'd did similar kind of things in Java and it does work.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

**Node API Code:**

```
app.get('/test', async function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  await updateData(parseInt(req.query['index'] as string));
  res.send('Hello World ' + req.query['index']);
});

let currentVersion: number = 0;
const timer = 20;

const updateData = async (index: number): Promise<void> => {
  const currentVersion = await getCurrentVersion();
  const latestVersion = currentVersion + 1;
  const s3FileName = "file_" + latestVersion + ".pdf";
  const seResult = await uploadFileToS3(currentVersion, s3FileName);
  console.log("S3 Result", seResult)
  setCurrentVersion(latestVersion);
  console.log("RequestNumber: ", index,  ", LastVersion: ", currentVersion, ", LatestVersion: ", latestVersion);
  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
}

const getCurrentVersion = async (): Promise<number> => {
  return currentVersion;
}

const setCurrentVersion = async (version: number): Promise<void> => {
  currentVersion = version;
}

const uploadFileToS3 = async (currentVersion: number, s3Filename: string): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(s3Filename);
    }, (timer - currentVersion) * 1000);
  })
}
```

**Client Code:**

```
for (let index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
        const url = "http://localhost:8081/test";
        fetch(url + `?index=${index}`)
          .then(x => x.text())
          .then(y => console.log(`${index} ` + y));
      }
```